# mkdir -p if final target is symlink

Tags: symlink, ln, mkdir

Say we have:

```
node_modules/
   suman/
```

and `node_modules/suman` is a symlink

if we do:

```
mkdir -p "$PWD/node_modules/suman"
```

I assume mkdir -p will not overrwrite the symlink?

what about if `$PWD/node_modules` is a symlink? I also assume `mkdir -p` will treat the symlink like a directory? Lastly, what if "node_modules" is symlinked to a file instead of a directory?

Answer (score 2):

As for `mkdir`, it's `man` makes it quite obvious about the first two subquestions:

> Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

As for the file symlink, a simple experiment should be enough:

```
$ touch a
$ ln -sr a A
$ mkdir -p A/b/c
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘A’: Not a directory
```

Comment: yeah I ask questions like these b/c I figure other people have things like this in their projects and it gets them thinking

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers said, if it's a symlink it will be treated like a file and fail. However, in case anyone else came here looking for a solution to treat the symlink like a directory, one of these will work:

```bsh
mkdir -p "$(realpath DIR)"
```

```bsh
mkdir -p "$(readlink -f DIR)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume (you didn't state explicitly) that node_modules exists as a directory or symlink in $PWD.

Handling your last question first - if node_modules is a file (or is a symlink to a file), it is forbidden from acting like a directory.  Thus, it could not have /suman as a subdirectory and

```
mkdir -p node_modules/anything
```

would fail with "Not a directory"

If suman exists as a file (or a link or symlink to either a file or a directory) in the directory node_modules, then

```
mkdir -p node_modules/suman
```

would fail with "File exists".

If suman exists as a directory (or a symlink to a directory) in the directory node_modules, then

```
mkdir -p node_modules/suman
```

would produce no error, but would not overwrite the existing directory or symlink.

Comment: I get no error when suman exists as a subdirectory. Apparently `mkdir` considers its job is done and exits with 0.

Comment: That's an interesting point @Tomasz.  If node_modules/suman exists and is a file, you'll get "File exists".  If node_modules/suman exists and is a directory, you won't get an error (from as long as you used -p).

Comment: So I think you should update your answer.